# Adding two chars into a short results in wrong answer

Tags: c, casting

I have a function that is aimed at getting the value of two chars added together into a short. It seems that the value is getting cut off or mangled.

Here is my code:

```
char rotate(char a, char b){
    unsigned short x = a + b;
    printf("init:%hu %hu = %hu\n", (unsigned char)a, (unsigned char)b,  (unsigned short)x);
    if(x > 255){
       x -= 255;
    }
    return (char) x;
}

unsigned char x = rotate((unsigned char)230, (unsigned char)100);
unsigned char y = rotate((unsigned char )200, (unsigned char)200);
unsigned char z = rotate((unsigned char) 230, (unsigned char)120);
```

and the results are

```
init:230 100 = 74
init:200 200 = 65424
init:230 120 = 94
```

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. Your `add` function returns `void`, but you are assigning its return value.

Comment: sorry it was modified when I posted it, putting it back the way it ran

Comment: You want to add them as a short, but you explicitly make sure that you return a char

Comment: Why aren't the arguments to your function unsigned chars?

Comment: Well, `x = a + b` doesn't store both `char` values in `x`, it just stores their sum. Besides, even if you managed to store both values in the `short`, you are throwing one away with the cast back to `char`. If you want to work with `unsigned char`, why don't you declare the function parameters to the `add` function as `unsigned char`?

Comment: @xing that works, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Addition is done with original values and is correct.

```
unsigned short x = a + b;
```

Yet display is done with converted values.

```
printf("init:%hu %hu = %hu\n", (unsigned char)a, (unsigned char)b, ....
```

---

Print the `char`  original values.

```
#if CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX
  printf("a:%d b:%d\n", a, b);
#else
  // this is rare
  printf("a:%u b:%u\n", a, b);
#endif
```

OP will see the first addition is `init:-26 100 = 74` and the sum of 74 is as expected.

---

With `init:200 200 = 65424`, the original  `char` values are -56.  -56 + -56 is -112.  Assigning -112 to a 16-bit `unsigned short` (0-65535) adds 65536 and then assigns.  `-112 + 65536` --> `65424`.